# Query performance on the partitioned table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds, partitioning

I have a partitioned table:

```
create table partitioned_table
(
    id                  bigint                   default nextval('url_verdict_sampled_id_seq'::regclass) not null,
    info                varchar(4096)                                                                    not null,
    scan_start_time     timestamp with time zone                                                         not null,
    constraint url_verdict_sampled_pkey
        primary key (id, scan_start_time),
)
    partition by RANGE (scan_start_time);

CREATE INDEX partitioned_table_info_index on partitioned_table(url);
```

and a partition definition:

```
create table partitioned_table_p2021_12_09
    partition of partitioned_table
        (
            constraint url_verdict_sampled_p2021_12_09_pkey
                primary key (id, scan_start_time),
        FOR VALUES FROM ('2021-12-09 00:00:00+00') TO ('2021-12-10 00:00:00+00');
```

I have a lot of partitions with quite large amount of records in them. However after the partitioning is done, this query performance is terrible(most of the average active sessions (AAS) are spent within lock_manager in accordance to the AWS Performance Insights). My Isolation level is set to read_commited:

```
SELECT * FROM partitioned_table WHERE info = $1
```

Once I add upper bound for the partition key the performance is somehow improved:

```
SELECT * FROM partitioned_table WHERE info = $1 AND scan_start_time >= $2
```

Is anyone aware about any other way to improve the query performance?

Comment: You can't create an index on a column ("url") that doesn't exist.

Comment: How many partitions?  What version?

Comment: And what is the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output?